# Kibana - How to count number of error logs and the type of error

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I monitor our team project error logs in Kibana and report them, like: From yesterday to today, there has been 50 errors, 20 of them is IP authentification and 30 Host error... or something like that.

I wanted to automate this process, counting the number of errors and their types and displaying them on Slack, kind of a microsoft teams. I was looking at web scrapping with python to extract those error logs but it doesn't quite look like what I'm looking for.

How would you go about this?

Comment: Which version of `ES` are you using ?
I have you taken a look at `Kibana Alerting` ? https://www.elastic.co/what-is/kibana-alerting

Answer (score 1):

Build a Watcher for that.

Query your stuff by timeframe, do the aggregations by "error category" & count your numbers, schedule the Watcher to fire at the frequency you're comfortable with, and send the results directly to Slack (connector is provided out of the box).

How to do it:
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/watcher-api-put-watch.html